# What does the grammatical tense of the verb "judged" in 1 Peter 4:6 tell us about the order of the events in the verse?

Tags: greek, grammar, 1-peter, grammatical-historical

In the following verse:

> For for this cause was **the gospel preached** also to them that are dead, **that they might be judged** according to men in the flesh, but **live according to God** in the spirit. (1 Peter 4:6)

It looks like the proper sequence of the described events is the following:

1) the gospel is preached > 2) they are judged according to men > 3) they live according to God

(the last two events can be happening simultaneously)

However, in [Russian Synodal Version](http://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0#.D0.93.D0.BB.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.B0_4) of the Bible, I found this rendering of the same verse:

> For for this cause was the gospel preached also to them that are
>   dead, that they, **having been judged** according to men in the flesh, might 
>   live according to God in the spirit. (1 Peter 4:6)

which could give us quite a different sequence:

1) judged according to men > 2) the gospel is preached  > 3) they live according to God

that is, the first two events are swapped.

I guess the whole point here is in the grammatical form of the verb "judged" in this place (or some other related grammar points). So, does the grammatical form of this verb in the original text make it clear whether the judgment took place before the preaching of the gospel or afterwards?

Answer (score 3):

The verse appears as follows in the Greek New Testament.

> [**1 Peter 4:6**](http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~fisher/cgi-bin/gnt?id=2104) (GNT)
>   <sup>6</sup> εἰς τοῦτο γὰρ καὶ νεκροῖς ***εὐηγγελίσθη*** ἵνα ***κριθῶσι*** μὲν κατὰ ἀνθρώπους σαρκὶ ***ζῶσι*** δὲ κατὰ θεὸν πνεύματι.

[NOTE: Arland *et al*. (2012) note no variants of this verse extant.]

There are three verbs in this verse:

**[*εὐαγγελίζω*](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?strongs=G2097&t=NASB)** = Aorist Passive Indicative (3 person singular) = "the gospel was preached"

**[*κρίνω*](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?strongs=G2919&t=NASB)** = Aorist Passive Subjunctive (3 person plural) = "they may be deemed"

**[*ζάω*](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?strongs=G2198&t=NASB)** = Aorist Active Subjunctive (3 person plural) = "they may live life"

In respective to these verbs and tenses, the literal sense of the Douay-Rheims 1899 American Edition provides the best translation.

> **[1 Peter 4:6](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Peter%204:6&version=DRA)** (Douay-Rheims 1899 American Edition)
>   <sup>6</sup> For, for this cause was the gospel preached also to the dead: that they might be judged indeed according to men, in the flesh; but may live according to God, in the Spirit.

The indicative mood indicates certainty ("was the gospel preached"), and the subjunctive mood indicates possibility ("they might be judged") and ("may live"). So the modified sequence proposed by the Original Post would be as follows:

```
  1) the gospel is preached > 
  2) they may be judged according to men > 
  3) they may live according to God
```

In simplified terms, the idea here is that all men are born dead in their spirit ([Rom 5:12](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=rom%205:12&version=NASB)), and so *to-the-dead* **is the Gospel preached** (aorist passive indicative), notwithstanding that these dead **may be deemed** (aorist passive subjunctive) as still-living mortals from the viewpoint of man. The desired end state is that these spiritually dead **may live** (aorist active subjunctive) according to God in spirit, so as to become spiritually alive and thus become "the living."

Both verses bring these thoughts together:

> **[1 Peter 4:5-6](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Peter%204:5-6&version=DRA)** (Douay-Rheims 1899 American Edition)
>   <sup>5</sup> Who shall render account to him, **who is ready to judge the living and the dead.** <sup>6</sup> For, for this cause was the gospel preached also to the dead: that they might be judged indeed according to men, in the flesh; but may live according to God, in the Spirit.

To recap, "the dead" and "the living" in this context are categories of living people; the difference is that the former are dead in spirit, notwithstanding that anyone may deem (or judge) them as mortals still living; and the latter are no longer dead spiritually, because they are now alive to God in spirit.

**REFERENCE:**
Arland, Kurt *et al*. (2012). *The Greek New Testament*. Stuttgart: Deutsche Bibelgesellschaft, 794.

Comment: 1) Thanks for your answer, but I am a bit bothered here. You said: "the idea here is that all men are born dead in their spirit...", so you are stating that when Peter was saying "Him, who is ready to judge the living and the dead", he meant the spiritual sense of the word ("dead in spirit"), rather than the physical sense ("physically dead"). However, phrases like "He will judge the living and the dead" or "He is the judge of the living and the dead" are quite common in the Scripture - they are almost like slang in koine - and they always refer to physical death.

Comment: 2)  Plus, the previous two times, in the same epistle, when Peter is using the word νέκρος ("dead"), he is definitely using that word in the physical sense: "...the resurrection of Jesus Christ from the dead" (1st Peter 1:3), "...God, that raised him up from the dead" (1st Peter 1:21). Good hermeneutics would be not to attach two different meanings to two same words used by the same author in the same epistle. I am afraid a strong argument is needed to support the idea that in 1st Peter 4:4-6 Peter suddenly switches from using the physical sense of the word to the spiritual one.

Comment: @brilliant - what did Jesus mean when he said to the disciples "let the dead bury the dead" (Matt 8:22)? It is not bad hermeneutics to say that Jesus was using "dead" in both the spiritual sense and the physical sense. In other words, Jesus said, "let the spiritually dead bury the physically dead." So it is not bad hermeneutics to see two nuances of "dead" in the same word grammatically in the same sentence. Otherwise, how would Jesus make any sense to say that physically dead people should bury other physically dead people?

Comment: 1) "what did Jesus mean when he said to the disciples "let the dead bury the dead" (Matt 8:22)? It is not bad hermeneutics to say that Jesus was using "dead" in both the spiritual sense and the physical sense" - In case of Matt 8:22 the very phrase "let the dead bury the dead" and its context give us a very strong basis to interpret the first "dead" in a spiritual sense (as physically dead people can't perform an act of burying) and the second "dead" in physical (it is highly unlikely that ↙

Comment: 2) the disciple was going to bury his father only because of his father's poor spiritual condition and not because of his poor physical state).  The second "dead" can also be interpreted in both senses. In 1st Peter 4:4-6, however, I don't see at the moment such a strong basis for such a drastic switch of the sense of the word.  In fact, there is even quite a strong basis for retaining the physical sense of the word: the previous two times that he has used the word "dead" in this epistle are all in physical sense, ↙

Comment: 3) and the third time he uses this word (1st Peter 4:5), he does it in the common expression ("Judge of both the living and the dead") that, if I am not wrong, is always used in the Scriptures only in the physical sense. It's not that I deny the spiritual interpretation here flat, I just need to be given (shown) a stronger basis for that.

Comment: @brilliant - Please see Acts 10:40-42, which is repeated in 2 Tim 4:1. Both passages refer to the judgment, which is yet future. The physically dead, who are also spiritually dead, will one day be resurrected to learn that their names are not found in the Book of Life (Rev 20:11-15). That is, the indictment was that their "dead works" were indicative of spiritual death. Since they are in physical bodies at this last judgment, they then are cast into the Lake of Fire, which, in essence, becomes the "Second (physical) Death" (Rev 20:15), since now they are physically dying yet a second time.

Comment: 1) @Joseph: "Please see Acts 10:40-42, which is repeated in 2 Tim 4:1. Both passages refer to the judgment, which is yet future" - I still don't understand the reason why the expression "judge both the living and the dead" in those passages should not be interpreted in the physical sense. To me, "both the living and the dead" implies the whole humanity - consisting of those who have already passed away and those who are still living. For sure, at the time when God's judgement starts there will still be some people physically alive, hence, we have "both living and the dead". ↙

Comment: 2) This phrase, in fact, was very common among Jews, and the physical sense in this phrase looks to me more plausible than spiritual - it is rather unlikely that Jews would imply spiritual sense in it as such concepts like "regenerated by the spirit", "born of the Spirit" or "dead in the spirit" were quite unclear and unfamiliar to them as we can tell from Nicodemus' talk to Jesus (John 3:6-10)

Comment: Nicodemus was chided for not understanding the new birth, which is the "washing away" of spiritual death. (It had nothing to do with re-entering the woman's womb, as Nicodemus inferred.) While the blood takes away sins, the water takes away spiritual death, which is why "living water" is synonymous with eternal life. The Spirit of God provides us this eternal life, thus the imagery of baptism. The physical illustration is water, but the spiritual is "living water."

Comment: 1) @Joseph: "**thus the imagery of baptism. The physical illustration is water, but the spiritual is "living water**" – Well, I would take issue here with your view on regeneration, baptism and baptism imagery. You seem to draw no distinction between the baptismal water and the living water, while to me they are quite different. The former one is hardly ever spoken of as flowing, while the latter one is almost always spoken of as flowing – like in John 4:14, 7:39, Rev. 22:1 (we know that in eternity future there will be the river of water of life flowing from the throne of God, but ↙

Comment: 2) there will be no more sea). The water of baptism is associated with the death and termination of our old natural man (like in Rom. 6:3-4), while the living water is associated with life and the birth of our new man. The former one deals with something negative, while the latter one does something positive. The former one is for “external use” – a person is either immersed into it, washed by it or sprinkled by it, while the latter one is exclusively for “internal use” – one has to drink of it in order to profit from it.↙

Comment: 3) Besides, I don’t think that the moment of regeneration, that is, the point, at which a person becomes a God-born child, necessarily takes place at the time when that person is being baptized in the water. However, I do believe that regeneration happens at the moment when a person believes, opens his heart to Jesus (prayer), and the Spirit of God (Rom. 8:9) – which is also the Spirit of Christ (Rom. 8:9), and is also called Spirit of adoption or sonship (Rom. 8:15) – enters into him and starts living in him. ↙

Comment: 4) This also means that that person joins the Lord in the spirit and becomes one with Him in his spirit (1 Cor. 6:17). This may take place before baptism, during the baptism or even after (in which case the baptism was probably not valid as it was not done out of faith). I believe that in case with ten disciples of the Lord this regeneration happened not on the day of Pentecost, but on the day of Jesus’ resurrection (at the moment when He breathed into them and said: “Receive the Holy Spirit” – John 20:22 ↙

Comment: 5) – Judah, as we know, was not there, and Thomas must’ve been regenerated one week later when he met Jesus again and believed into Him), which somehow corresponds to Peter’s words in 1st Pet. 1:3: “God … has begotten us … by the resurrection of Jesus Christ”. Incidentally, the Scripture doesn’t tell us that the twelve disciples chosen by Him at the beginning of His ministry were ever baptized in the water, though we know that they themselves were baptizing others. ↙

Comment: 6) However, the matter of baptism and all the imagery related to it is quite off-topic here. For the present thread it will suffice to establish that Nicodemus was quite puzzled when the Lord started talking to him about life and death in spiritual terms. The matter of spiritual birth – that is, the matter of passing from spiritual death into life – was completely out of his frame of reference. ↙

Comment: 7) So, if the Pharisee Nicodemus, a ruler of Jews and a master of Israel, was so puzzled by these spiritual things when they were first mentioned to him, then we won’t commit an error by suggesting that these things would be equally, if not all the more so, puzzling to the centurion Cornelius who was not a Jew, but rather “one of another nation”, keeping a company with whom was “unlawful for a Jew” (Acts 10:28) – even despite the fact that he was a God-fearing gentile and of good report among Jews (Acts 10:22). ↙

Comment: 8) And for sure such a phrase like “both the living and the dead” would be firstly understood by him only in the physical sense as such concepts like “physically living, but spiritually dead” or “physically dead, but spiritually alive” were simply not yet familiar to him – just like they were first not familiar to Nicodemus. Peter, of course, realized that; therefore, I make a conclusion that when Peter was using the phrase “both the living and the dead” in his first preaching to Nicodemus and his kinsmen and friends he was using it in the physical sense. ↙

Comment: 9) If you look, by the way, at what kind of things Peter was preaching to them, you will notice the content of that preaching that was accessible to the audience: Jesus’ acts of “doing good”, His miracles of healing, His death and resurrection, His judgment, and the forgiveness of sins to those who believe in Him – nothing about being born of God or being born of the Spirit, and nothing about being spiritually dead or alive.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of 1 Peter 4:6 is that christians who have died were preached to while physically alive on earth and they believed and received Christ before dying physically. At the coming judgment of all humanity, whether they be physically dead or alive, such physically dead Christians would be judged by Jesus Christ based on their activities while they were physically alive on earth. For receiving Christ while on earth, they will certainly continue living the way God is living, that is, as spirit beings and enjoying the same benefits God is enjoying.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange.  Please consider [registering an account](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) to fully take advantage of what this site has to offer and taking the [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn what we are about.  This is a good start, but to be a good answer you need to revise your post to either cite references that back your position or to more thoroughly explain how you get this interpretation from the text itself.